# How to add data in table in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, grails-domain-class

Hi I am a newbie to Vaadin.

I am using Table property of vaadin to load the data from Domain Class but i have no idea how to set the `table.additem` for the data. 
I am using the following code to generate the column value

```
Table table = new Table("Customer Table");
  table.addContainerProperty("Street", String.class, null);
    for(DomainClass domainClass :  domainClassList) {
           //     table.addItem(domainClass.getStreet());
    }
layout.addComponent(table);
```

But it is showing the empty page.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Vaadin best-practice is to work with Containers.

```
final Table table = new Table("Customer Table");
final BeanItemContainer<DomainClass> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(
            DomainClass.class, domainList);
table.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

If the DomainClass has a getter `getStreet()` then it's automatically mapped to a column with that name. Still you can set the table headers manually with `table.setColumnHeader("street", "Street");`

Maybe you find [Vaadin's docs about Containers](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-container.html) useful too.

Comment: this is what i am searching Thank you so much :)

Comment: I am getting the error outOfMemory Message : GC overhead limit exceed

Comment: If your list of objects is very large and the objects have many members, you can use lazy loading to save memory and use smaller objects, i.e. DTOs. Please check out my demo on lazy loading here: https://github.com/apm78/demo-lazyquerycontainer. It uses the LazyQueryContainer, Vaadin's recommended container for large data sets. It's an addon you can find in the directory (https://vaadin.com/directory).